# Facing CORS In Node framework NestJS-6.3.1

Tags: nestjs

### I am developing a Node base project using nestJs => 6.3.1 framework. I have enabled all cors still I am facing following error

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:3000' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

core.js:7187 ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "localhost:3000", ok: false, …}

#### I have tried the following ways but still facing the same issue.

1.
      var app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule,{cors:true});
      await app.listen(3000);

2. var app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
     const options = {
       origin: '*',
       methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
       preflightContinue: false,
       optionsSuccessStatus: 204,
       credentials: true,
       allowedHeaders: 'Content-Type, Accept',
     };
     console.log(app);
     app.enableCors(options);
     await app.listen(3000);

   ```
   import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
   import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

   async function bootstrap() {
     var app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
     const options = {
       origin: '*',
       methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
       preflightContinue: false,
       optionsSuccessStatus: 204,
       credentials: true,
       allowedHeaders: 'Content-Type, Accept',
     };
     console.log(app);
     app.enableCors(options);
     await app.listen(3000);
   }
   bootstrap();
   ```

Expected output: Server should allow processing cros origin request but it gives following issue or error.

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:3000' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read the error message carefully:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:3000' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

You aren't making a request over HTTP (or HTTPS) so your server (which is an HTTP server) can't be responding to it, so nothing you do to the code running your server will make a difference.

You need to change the code that requests a URL starting with `localhost:3000` and change it to `http://localhost:3000`

Comment: @kamleshgorasiya — The error message makes it clear that your client-side code is requesting `localhost:3000` when it should be requesting `http://localhost:3000`. The fact that you can successfully request data when you use Postman just means that you are typing the URL correctly when you use that tool.

Comment: I am very Sorry, You were right, I was making API call without http